# Counter-example of an ordered set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have difficulties understanding the notion of ordered sets, and I was wondering if someone could provide a relation $\mathcal{R}$ on a set $S$ such that equipped with that relation $S$ is not an ordered set?

---

A *relation* $\mathcal{R}$ on a set $S$ is a subset $\mathcal{R} \subseteq S \times S$.

A relation $\mathcal{R}$ on a set $S$ is called an *ordering* if the following properties are satisfied:

1. $(x,x) \in \mathcal{R}$ for each $x \in S$.
2. If $(x,y),(y,z) \in \mathcal{R}$, then $(x,z) \in \mathcal{R}$.
3. If $(x,y),(y,x) \in \mathcal{R}$, then $x=y$.

Comment: @Surb thank for your reply. Could you elaborate and tell me why $\mathbb{C}$ is not ordered (I'm sorry if this is really obvious, but I'm self-studying, and the book I'm reading seems very confusing)?

Comment: You probably mean to ask: provide a relation $\mathcal R$ on a set $S$ such that equipped with that relation $S$ is not an ordered set.

Comment: @drhab thanks, yeah, that is exactly what I mean (although I'm not sure how that is different from what I've written above). Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $S$ is not empty, then $\varnothing$ is a relation on $S$ which is not an order relation (not partial, nor linear).

If your definition of order is irreflexive, then $\varnothing$ is in fact a partial order, since no two elements are comparable; in which case $S\times S$ will do the trick.

If by ordered set you really just mean linear orders, then $\mathcal P(X)$ ordered by $\subseteq$ is an example, if $X$ has more than one element. Other examples are ordering $\Bbb N$ by divisibility (so $\langle n,m\rangle\in\cal R$ if and only if there is some $k$ such that $n\cdot k=m$), which is of course not linear.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my question to include the definitions used in the book I'm reading.

Comment: Okay, the definition is for what is often called *a partial ordered set*. So the first example, of $\varnothing$ when $S\neq\varnothing$ works; as well $S\times S$ when $S$ has more than one element also works.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It seems like an nice example. I will wait for a bit with accepting the answer so to give other people a chance of answering.

Comment: Sure, I'm always in favor of waiting before accepting!